# How to render "£" in the console with a uk (cp850 or iso) keyboard

Tags: fonts, console, keyboard, freebsd

I have just installed freebsd FreeBSD 10.0 onto an old Thinkpad X60. I am taking it slowly to make sure all the details are right. The laptop has a uk keyboard. This is working correctly in the terminal apart from two keys which show a character value instead of rendering. Setting the keyboard to uk.iso (with kbdmap) changes the value shown.

```
                   [as root]        [as ivan]
key        want    cp850     iso    cp850     iso
shift-3       £     \234    \243    <009c>    <00a3>
shift-`       ¬     \252    \254    <00aa>    <00ac>
```

The values displayed also differ depending on the login (ivan is logged in with zsh). Ivan's displayed values are the character codes for the expected characters.

Changing the keymap or font --- either with kbdmap and vidfont, or by editing /etc/rc.conf and rebooting --- seems to have no effect.

The only relevant-looking screenmap I have is iso-8859-1_to_cp437.scm. Adding this to /etc/rc.conf and reebooting has no effect.

Am I missing a screenmap? If so, which ones do I need and where can I get them?

Is there anything else I should be doing to get this keyboard rendering properly?

It would be acceptable if root's console keyboard was limited.

With thanks and best wishes,

Ivan

Comment: Are you perhaps using the new `vt(4)` console?

Comment: Don't know  :)  I don't have the X60 any more, but I have the same problem with a W530 with a US keyboard (FreeBSD 10.1).  Thanks.

Comment: Look at `/var/run/dmesg.boot`. If you see `VT: running with driver "vga"` in the beginning of that file, you're using `vt(4)`.

Comment: No.  Looks like I'm running sc?  sc0: <System console> at flags 0x100 on isa0  \\  
sc0: VGA <16 virtual consoles, flags=0x300>

Comment: Then changing the keymap and font *should* work. Maybe ask on the `freebsd-questions` mailing list?

Comment: How to render "£" in the console with a uk (cp850 or iso) ke  /  Discussion in 'General' started by ivan_llaisdy, Feb 15, 2014.  /  https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/how-to-render-in-the-console-with-a-uk-cp850-or-iso-ke.44934/

Comment: Is the mailing list any better than the forum?

Comment: To be honest, I never use the forum since I prefer the mailing list.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Can you now answer your own question? Side note: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337974/13260 under _How do I change currently selected keyboard layout from command line?_

Comment: No, gave up and freebsd and now using lubuntu :(